# Reproduce a complex curl request with httr2 or httr

Tags: r, curl, proxy, httr, httr2

I usually scrape web pages with `rvest::read_html()`; however, this time I want to read an html page using a residential proxy:

Proxy username: `username`

Proxy password: `password`

Proxy hostname: `geo.iproyal.com` (my residential proxy service)

Proxy port: `port`

Let's also assume that I'm trying to read the following web page: `https://ipv4.icanhazip.com`

The website for my residential proxy service provide the following `curl` request which works perfectly:

```
$ curl -v -x http://username:password@geo.iproyal.com:port -L https://ipv4.icanhazip.com
```

where `$` refers to a bash shell.

My goal is to reproduce this `curl` request using `{httr}` or `{httr2}`. Here is my (failed) attempt:

```
req <- httr2::request(base_url = url) |>
    httr2::req_proxy(
      url = "geo.iproyal.com",
      port = port,
      username = username,
      password = password,
      auth = "basic"
)
```

This returns a "403 forbidden" error message.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Was there an error msg?

Comment: @Chris I get a "403 forbidden" error message.

Comment: Sounds like credentials (usr/pwd).

Comment: @Chris The `curl` command works perfectly. So it is likely that my `{httr2}` implementation is not quite correct.

Comment: Looking at `library(curl)`, does `curl_version()` report `$httr2 [1] TRUE`? And what is your OS?